# Invalid key error when using url.<base>.insteadOf on Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-config

When I want to predefine URL changes in my global git config on Ubuntu I can use this command:
url..pushInsteadOf

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf

Everything works fine and I get a new entry in my `.gitconfig` file. However, if I try this on windows with cmd it throws this error:

```
error: invalid key: url.https://test:x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompany.insteadOf.https://github.com/MyCompany
```

How can I achieve the same on a windows machine?

Comment: The key must be `url.https://test:x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompany.insteadOf` and the value `https://github.com/MyCompany`

Comment: So what would the command look like in its entirety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper command to create configuration must be

```
git config url.https://test:x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompany.insteadOf https://github.com/MyCompany
```

Note the space between the key and the value.

You also should remove the wrong key from `.gitconfig`.